F# - Use generics from a Type (for use EntityMapFluentDefinition of RepoDB)
I'm trying to use F# and RepoDB.
RepoDB does not manage Option, a TypeHandler is required.
Given I have a User entity with AuthToken property defined as "string option" I need to do this in order to have RepoDB working within that field.
FluentMapper
    .Entity<User>().Table("Users") 
    .PropertyHandler<StringOptionTypeHandler>(User.GetField(fun u -> u.AuthToken)) |> ignore

I still don't know if .GetField works... but here it is:
type User with
    static member GetField (expr:Expression<Func<User, obj>>) =
        RepoDb.Field.Parse<User>(expr) |> Seq.head

Now, I need t odo this for every Option of every "entity" I have in my project.
So, I have a generic TypeHandler:
type OptionTypeHandler<'T when 'T : null> () = 
    interface IPropertyHandler<'T, Option<'T>> with 
        member this.Set (input:Option<'T>, options:PropertyHandlerSetOptions): 'T = 
            match input with
            | Some x -> x
            | None -> null

        member this.Get (input:'T, options:PropertyHandlerGetOptions) = 
            match input with
            | null -> None
            | value -> Some(value)

and I'm iterating trough all the entities, extracting their Option properties and trying to map the TypeHandler:
    (Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof<User>) |> nonNull)
        .DefinedTypes
        |> Seq.where (fun e -> e.Namespace = typeof<User>.Namespace)
        |> Seq.iter (fun e -> 
            let entity = e.AsType() // from TypeInfo to Type

            try
                let tableName = 
                    match tableNames.TryGetValue (entity |> nonNull) with
                    | true, table -> table
                    | _ -> failwith $"Entity \"{entity.Name}\" table name is not mapped."

                let table = MapGenerator().GenerateEntityMap entity //:?> EntityMapFluentDefinition<_>
    // :?> EntityMapFluentDefinition<_> <-- thisis the casrt I need but... can't find the way to manage it otherwise

                let optionProperties = 
                    e.DeclaredProperties
                    |> Seq.where (fun p -> isOption p.PropertyType)

                mapOptionProperties table optionProperties
            with
                | ex -> failwith $"Failed to set RepoDB entity mapping for \"{entity.Name}\". {ex}"
        )


I can generate a EntityMapFluentDefinition but I can't specify its generic type !
type MapGenerator<'e when 'e: not struct> () =

    member this.GenerateMap (entityType:Type) =
        let genericMethod =
            (typeof<FluentMapper>.GetMethod("Entity") |> nonNull)
                .MakeGenericMethod(entityType)

        genericMethod.Invoke(null, [||]) //:?> EntityMapFluentDefinition<'e>


let mapOptionProperties<'a when 'a: not struct and 'a: null> (table:EntityMapFluentDefinition<'a>) (properties: seq<PropertyInfo>) =
    properties 
    |> Seq.iter (fun p ->
        let propertyType = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
        try
            let (handlerType:OptionTypeHandler<'a>) = createTypeHandler<'a> ()
            table.PropertyHandler (p.Name, handlerType) |> ignore
        with
        | ex -> failwith $"Failed to create TypeHandler for \"{p.Name}\". {ex}"
    )


and... without that generic type definition, I can't have a valid EntityMapFluentDefinition<'e> that I can use.
So, given a Type "E" how can I cast to something ?
I belivee that a Type generated at runtime is not usable so this seems an impossible thing to do.
Using reflection I can create the Type of EntityMapFluentDefinition<'e>... but is still a type and cast is not the way.
